# How to make the picture from my website displayed when posting the url on LinkedIn correctly

Tags: c#, facebook, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I pasted the url of a webpage from my website in FaceBook, it works fine amd allows me to choose one of three pictures on that page.

I pasted the same url in LinkedIn, the main picture does not get picked by the LinkedIn, and only 2 pics which are displayed on the side panel get picked.

I only have this

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Is there anything else I have to do to make it works correct on both websites?

PS:
I saw many posts about the open-graph and tried some, none of them work for me.

Comment: Could you provide a copy of your open graph tags, or perhaps the URL of the site?  Hard to help when we have no information to work with.

Comment: hi @JustinKominar thank you for your reply. The one-line code is all I have for the OpenGraph. Is it enough? Or do I have to add more code?

Comment: If that's all you have, then no - you have not implemented OpenGraph properly.  Check out http://ogp.me/ for the proper way to do it.